# How to print only part of an Excel column on pycharm?

Tags: python, pandas

Using:

```
import pandas as pd
x = pd.read_excel(r"C:\Users\nan\PycharmProjects\giraffe\GENERA.xlsx", engine="openpyxl")
print(x)
```

I can easily print the entire sheet from Excel into pycharm, but I needed only the first 5 lines of the Excel document. How can I do that?

Comment: Try `print(x.head(5))`

Answer (score 0):

May be you want to use [pandas.DataFrame.head()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.head.html)

```py
x.head(5)
```